# Geonames Cities [postalcodes] table

Tags: php, mysql, geonames

How i can prevent to receive cities with its subsites and get only the biggest village.

Example:
Currently i get 2 records the first is the main city and the second a neighbor. But i want only the main town.

```
CH  8280    Kreuzlingen    
CH  8285    Kreuzlingen Ifolor AG <--- needed to be excluded
```

Regards Sascha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Found ^_^

You need to detect the first blank space between the town in a foreach loop or similar loop and the $suggestions array contains only the hometowns without its same neighbors.

Example:

```
foreach ($suggestion_cities as $key => $city) {
    if(preg_match('/\s/',$city->city)) {
        continue;
    }
    $suggestions[] = array(
        'value' => $city->city,
        'value_type' => 'city'
    );
}
```